# How to iterate through Elasticsearch source using Apache Spark?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am trying to build a recommendation system by integrating Elasticsearch with Apache Spark. I am using Java. I am using movilens dataset as example data. I have indexed the data to Elasticsearch as well. So far, I have been able to read the input from Elasticsearch index as follows:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Example App").setMaster("local");
conf.set("spark.serializer", org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.class.getName());
        conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost");
        conf.set("es.port", "9200");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>> esRDD = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(sc, "movielens/recommendation");
```

Using esRDD.collect() function, I can see that I am retrieving the data from elastic search correctly. Now I need to feed the user id, item id and preference from the Elasticsearch result to Spark's recommendation. If I am using a csv file, I would be able to do it as follows:

```
String path = "resources/user_data.data";
        JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(path);
        JavaRDD<Rating> ratings = data.map(
          new Function<String, Rating>() {
            public Rating call(String s) {
              String[] sarray = s.split("   ");
              return new Rating(Integer.parseInt(sarray[0]), Integer.parseInt(sarray[1]), 
                                Double.parseDouble(sarray[2]));
            }
          }
        );
```

What could be an equivalent mapping if I need to iterate through the elastic search output stored in esRDD and create a similar map as above? If there is any example code that I could refer to, that would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not answering the Spark question directly, but in case you missed it, there is a description of doing recommendations on MovieLens data using elasticsearch here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_significant_terms_demo.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was using https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-taste plugin before to use Mahout's item recommendation features. The problem I ended up with was  that each user had different level of access to the data. One user may not be able to access the entire dataset and hence, the recommendation for them should be from within the subset of dataset that they have access to. I could not figure out way of doing that with this plugin. Do you have any experience with that plugin? I hadn't looked into the significant_terms feature, will explore it now.

Comment: After exploring the significant_term feature, it seems like it is suitable if there is a clearly defined preference (for example: movie liked or not). But for me, the user preference value makes a lot of difference. The user preference is not simply calculated based on whether the user likes the movie or not but on various other factors as well. Will it be possible to take such considerations into account when using significant_terms?

Comment: When I used significant_terms on this dataset I chose to index each user with a list of the movies they liked (4 or 5 star ratings). That seemed to produce good recommendations when presented with a single movie ID and analyzing all users with that like.

Comment: I'm also working on a "sampling" aggregation that would analyze only the top-scoring set of users for a query. This would be wrapped around the significant_terms agg to prevent it analyzing low-quality matches. This would allow fuzzier queries for the selection process e.g. one with a whole range of movies and boosts and Lucene would rank the top quality N matching users e.g those with many shared movie choices that weren't necessarily just mainstream movies everyone has seen.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the format of the data in ElasticSearch. But let's assume it has fields `userId`, `movieId` and `rating` so an example document looks something like `{"userId":1,"movieId":1,"rating":4}`.

Then you should be able to do (ignoring null checks etc):

```
JavaRDD<Rating> ratings = esRDD.map(
    new Function<Map<String, Object>, Rating>() {
        public Rating call(Map<String, Object> m) {
              Int userId = Integer.parseInt(m.get("userId"));
              Int movieId = Integer.parseInt(m.get("movieId"));
              Double rating = Double.parseDouble(m.get("rating"));
              return new Rating(userId, movieId, rating);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But the data format is as follows: {user_id=26, items=[{item_id=1123, value=0.39811674}, {item_id=445, value=0.13920784}, {item_id=1129, value=0.12835233}}, so it's not Map<String, Object> but JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>>. Any idea how to parse that one?

Comment: JavaRDD<Map<String,Object>> esRDDVal = esRDD.values(); That's all I needed to do and use the iteration as you described above. It is working now. Thanks.